# Why does 'data = data.rename(columns={"Session": "preORpost"})' not work when executing a code in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python code and the following lines do not seem to be working:

```
# Rename "Session" column to "preORpost"
# and translate "preORpost" and "Site" number code
data = data.rename(columns={"Session": "preORpost"})
data.loc[:, "preORpost"] = data.loc[:, "preORpost"].map({1: "PRE", 2: "POST"})
data.loc[:, "Site"] = data.loc[:, "Site"].map({1: "VERTEX", 2: "LEFT", 3: "RIGHT"})
```

The key error is the following: 
KeyError: 'the label [preORpost] is not in the [columns]'

Anyone could advice what is going on?

Comment: can you post the output of `print(data.columns)`? Also, try `data.rename(columns={"Session": "preORpost"}, errors="raise")` so you can see what the problem is.

Comment: check if the name `Session` is correct